# Read-Only File System after Upgrade Kernel under CentOS 7

Tags: linux-kernel, google-cloud-platform

## Read-Only File System after Upgrade Kernel under CentOS 7

---

Hi all,
   I upgraded the kernel of CentOS 7 to `4.11.4`, and reboot the VM. After that, I cannot change anything in the system. No matter what I do, it says `Read-only file system`.
   I want to work with the latest kernel, what's the correct way to upgrade kernel under CentOS 7 on Google Cloud Engine?

  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try remounting the filesystem

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda3
```

Comment: thanks! this solved my problem in the Ubuntu 18 instances in GCP!