# my Laravel application has a problem on Google Cloud. The stream or file "/srv/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

The laravel application working well in my local.
But when I upload it to Google App Engine, using command `gcloud app deploy`. Then it give me error writing logs.

```
UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/srv/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Read-only file system
```

The code is app.yaml file in root folder of my laravel app.

## Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.

runtime: php72

## api_version: 1

## threadsafe: true

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: public/favicon.ico
  upload: public/favicon.ico

- url: .*
  script: auto

env_variables:
  # Uncomment the following to enable debug mode.

## APP_DEBUG: 0

APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: base64:nzd12xL4YtD3fIKYYRc/NGIfA+phk39fGJrvq11UBug=
  APP_LOG_LEVEL: debug
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp

DB_HOST: ''
  DB_USERNAME: ''
  DB_PASSWORD: ''
  DB_DATABASE: ''

CACHE_DRIVER: memcache
  SESSION_DRIVER: memcache
  MAIL_DRIVER: 'mail'
  LOG_DRIVER: 'syslog'

STORAGE_PATH: 'gs://#default#/laravel/storage'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C9K1.png)

Comment: `After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read-Only File System after Upgrade Kernel under CentOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522986/read-only-file-system-after-upgrade-kernel-under-centos-7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File permissions for Laravel 5 (and others)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite where Laravel stores things as per step (1) and (3) in these instructions:

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard

Briefly -

Step 1, in app.yaml you need to add:

```
APP_STORAGE: /tmp
```

Then in Step 3 you make Laravel use this. Modify bootstrap/app.php by adding the following block of code before the return statement. This will allow you to set the storage path to /tmp for caching in production.

```
# [START] Add the following block to `bootstrap/app.php`
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Set Storage Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script allows you to override the default storage location used by
| the  application.  You may set the APP_STORAGE environment variable
| in your .env file,  if not set the default location will be used
|
*/
$app->useStoragePath(env('APP_STORAGE', base_path() . '/storage'));
# [END]
```